# How to getElementsByClassname from another url?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to make a web page with some data from another url.

[Link I want data from](https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&sort=lh&app=433850_1&search_item=%22Skin%3A%20Pinstripe%20Suit%20Jacket%22)

I want to get the 5 cheapest item prices to my page. Is it possible to use `getElementsByClassname` to get the prices? I know that the class of the prices is `item-amount`.

Comment: Learn about the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: see PHP curl...

Comment: You appear to want to do web scraping. There are many tools out there for this. Have a look at this article http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/web-scraping-tools/ ( A comparison of various scraping tools), but don't take it as a definitive answer - use Google to help you search

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using GET request to obtain the data.

If so, then the data must be in JSON format. From there on it is easy. You can't use getElementsByClassName because it doesn't understand that language.

Let's assume you have the JSON data as.

```
[{
  "name": "belt",
  "price": "$2"
}, {
  "name": "shirt",
 "price": "$10"
}]
```

In this case, you can use the data simply by accessing the price property.

Comment: https://api.opskins.com/IPricing/GetAllLowestListPrices/v1/?appid=433850 i can access this, but then i only get the lowest price item, not the 5 lowest price items! :/

Comment: can you explain that better for me @Ted? :) I am in the learning process of this some in not so good at this yet..

Comment: @MathiasHermansen so assuming you can get the entire list of item prices, could you sort the list and then take the top 5 cheapest?